# NodeJS to query Postgres data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, node-postgres

I have data in Postgres with 3 columns (id_buyer, supplier, survey_exp) and am using node to query the data in queries.js file. Then in my index.js i do

```
app.get('/ss/:id', db.getSSExp)
```

to get me a link with JSON data. In this scenario I have a specific query that should output suppliers with surveys expiring within 6 months. My query isn't working right (node server throws an error and 'site cannot be reached') and i believe $1 helps node identify what parameter I am specifically searching for in the url (i.e. localhost:3000/ss/id_buyer). Any help would be great!

```
const getSSExp = (request, response) => {
const id = request.params.id

pool.query('SELECT * FROM supplier_survey WHERE id_buyer = $1 and survey_exp 
<= CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL "6 MONTH"', [id], 
(error, results) => {
    if (error) {
        throw error
    }
    response.status(200).json(results.rows)
})
}

module.exports = { getSSExp }
```

Comment: Please tell us more about "*My query isn't working right*". What exactly is the problem?

Comment: It says that the site cannot be reached and node server throws an error during reboot

Comment: And *what* error does it throw during reboot? (And does that startup error even have anything to do with your database query?)

Comment: I believe it is the way i am handling dates in Postgres, cause the error it throws is "error at line 113"

Answer (score 0):

Without more info about how the results are wrong in your current query, I'll have to make some guesses.

- Should be: survey_exp **<=**

Less than or equal starts with the less than symbol. Not sure what the reverse is doing since it was apparently accepted by the parser.

- MySQL interval syntax won't work; use one of the following instead:

  - CURRENT_DATE + '6 MONTH'::interval
  - CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '6 MONTH'

Comment: Thanks, edited my question with correct interval syntax and a few more changes. Still no luck

Comment: `"6 MONTH"` Double quotes tells PostgreSQL the value is an identifier (variable name, column name, table name, etc.) rather than a scalar value, which is what you are trying to use. Use double quotes or back quote for the whole query, and put single quotes around `'6 MONTH'` instead. Alternatively, just escape the single quotes (`\'`).

Answer (score 0):

So found out that the way date is uploaded into DB matters and my dates were of type 'string' so had to convert to date and state the way date is formatted in my columns. So after making the following modifications to my code it worked...for anyone in the future running into this silly problem.

`"Select * FROM supplier_survey where to_date(survey_exp,'MM/DD/YYYY') > NOW() AND to_date(survey_exp,'MM/DD/YYYY') <= NOW() + '5 months' AND  id_buyer = $1 Order By survey_exp"`